# How to provide access to the Internet for a second computer ?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

There are two computers on 1 worth Windows 8.1 and two network cards and a second computer on which stands in Ubuntu.
How to grant access to the computer on which stands Ubuntu internet access?

In the settings of the network connection I share the internet access to the network to which the computer is connected to the second. On the side of Ubuntu I have tried different types of connection.

Comment: Why not use a router/switch?

Comment: Because I have none. This system worked before I reinstalled windows.

Comment: You say you 'tried different types of connection' Could you specify what you mean by that and what you tried? The Windows box should be a DHCP server if you enable Internet Connection Sharing.

Comment: In IPv4 Settings. I choose "Automatic (DHCP)" and "Automatic (DHCP)andrees only". With this methods сonnection does not work. With Method "Shared to other computers" but the connection is access to the Internet is not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your Ubuntu machine is already set up.

### Reading previous settings from Ubuntu:

Click the networking icon in the dock and click *Edit connections…*. Select *Auto ethernet* and click *Edit*. Navigate to *IPv4 Settings* tab. Take a note whether *Method* is *Automatic (DHCP)* or *Manual*. In the latter case, take not of IPs under *Address* and *Gateway*.

[image: Ubuntu connection configuration with relevant fields underlined]

### Setting up Windows:

Right-click networking icon in the notification area and choose *Open Network and Sharing Center*. Select *Change adapter settings* from the left pane. You should see at least two adapters, including one working wired connection and one disconnected. Right-click the latter one and click *Properties*. Select *Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)* and click *Properties*. A new window will open.

Select *Use the following IP address:*. Next steps will depend on whether Ubuntu was configured for automatic or manual IP assignment.

#### Manual config:

You should have taken note of *Gateway* you had configured on Ubuntu. Enter that IP address in the *IP Address* field (**not** *Default gateway*). *Subnet mask* will be filled in automatically. Leave *Default gateway* empty and enter some DNS servers. I prefer Google DNS, which are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` (respectively preferred and alternative). Click *OK* and scroll down to next header (skip DHCP config).

[image: Example of IP configuration on Windows machine]

#### Automatic (DHCP) config:

You'll have to check the IP settings of your primary network adapter to avoid address collision. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Command prompt will appear. Type `ipconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Scroll to the top and look for your primary ethernet adapter's *IPv4 Address* (note that it's different than your external IP and will probably begin with `192.168`).

You'll have to choose some different IP address class for your new connection. IP address class is a range of IPs. First octet must be `192` and second one should be `168`. Last octet will be reserved for actual IPs and third one is of your choice.

For example if your main adapter has the IP `192.168.0.101`, you can choose `192.168.1.x` for your second adapter's network class. Fourth octet will be a number from range 1-254, different for each of your machines. For internet-sharing devices (like your Windows machine) choosing `1` or `100` is common.

Enter settings just like in manual config case (described above), but use the IP of your choice (previously choosen address class and fourth octet) as *IP Address*.

#### Enabling Internet sharing

**This step is necessary both for manual and automatic IP assignment.**

You should be back in your connection's properties. Switch to *Sharing* tab and enable *Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection*. Choose your primary network adapter from the list below. Click *OK*. Internet sharing should start working in a moment.

Comment: Configured manually. Still does not work. 
Maybe I'm wrong where tick with share Internet. 
I have two network cards and proper internet connection. 
I sharing network card that connects to the Internet.

Comment: That's correct. Try DHCP on Ubuntu and configure Windows appropriately according to my description. If it won't work switch Ubuntu to manual and use Windows' IP as Ubuntu's gateway, then enter the same address with last octet incremented as Ubuntu's IP, set netmask to `255.255.255.0`.